# Table View Cell error

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have two table view in one view controller.

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if (tableView.tag==0) {

              TableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
              if (!cell) {
             cell=[[TableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
        }

           int storyIndex = [indexPath indexAtPosition: [indexPath length] - 1];

           cell.title.text=[[stories objectAtIndex: indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"title"];

           cell.title.numberOfLines=6;

           return cell;}
    else
        {
            static NSString *CellIdentifier2 = @"Cell2";

            TableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier2];
            if (cell == nil)
            {
                cell = [[TableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier2] ;
            }
            int row =indexPath.row;

            if (row==0) {
                cell.title.text =@"All Songs";
            }
            else
            cell.title.text = [categoryArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row-1];


            return cell;}

    }
```

For the first (tableView.tag==0) table everything it's ok , but for the second :

```
2015-02-18 11:53:11.733 Karaoke Final Project[2722:808305] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewCell title]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb4d2c48bb0'
```

For both table view cell i set the same class TableViewCell.

If tableView.tag != 0 i put

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier2];


     if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier2] ;
        }
```

I don't have problems.

Comment: How many tables are there ? Are you sure that you set the correct class name to the cell ?

Comment: two tables . Yes, the name is correct.

Comment: Is `TableViewCell` is a custom cell or its a typo mistake? because in cell intialization you are using `UITableViewCell `.

Comment: TableViewCell is a custom cell . I changed cell initialization and i dont have any errors , but my table is empty even if i set an outlet for title .

Answer (score 0):

All cell objects are `UITableViewCell` type, because you alloc them as such ones. And as far as I know `UITableViewCell` does not have property named "title".

```
TableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
```

It does not make your object `TableViewCell` type. It just creates pointer of this type. It works, because you inherit from `UITableViewCell` in `TableViewCell`.

You should try this:

```
cell = [[TableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier2] ;
```

instead of:

```
cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier2] ;
```

in both cases.

Comment: I changed . now it's ok . but my table view is empty . I set an outlet to TableViewCell which is a custoum cell.

Answer (score 0):

```
cell=[[TableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
```

the return type of cell type is `UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle` so there is no property `title` is this style.

You have to use either

```
cell.textLabel.text = @"Title";
```

or

```
cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Details";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        static NSString *CellIdentifier2 = @"Cell2";
        TableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier2];
        if (cell == nil)
        {
             NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SimpleTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
             cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        }
```

use the code above.... for more details visit this link..

http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/